# seekg does not work after while(file.good()) {....}

Tags: seekg

I'm fairly perturbed that the below does not appear to work.

```
while(myfile.good())
{   
    myfile.get(holdc);      
    ....................
}

//does not work 
myfile.seekg(0);
myfile.read(buffer,5);
sentence.push_back(buffer);
cout << buffer<<endl;
delete[] buffer;
```

I have tried myfile.close, etc., even creating a new `ifstream myfile2;` to reload the file. Nothing works. It's as if this seekg thing is universal or something, and works only once per program.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta thanks for the edit, I was indeed "perturbed" :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears, right after

```
    while(myfile.good())
 {   
    myfile.get(holdc);      
    ....................
}
```

I need to do

```
myfile.clear();
```

However, I still need to know how to go ahead through the new line and read form file. After the first line ends I get random symbols. Anyone?

edit**

What happened was I used a dynamic array char buffer, which needs to be closed with:

```
buffer[i] = 0;
```